# Oracle extract json fields

Tags: sql, json, oracle

I have the below json. Is there any Oracle way to extract all the values under deviceNumber regarless of the previous fields?

```
{
   "session":{
      "sessionStartDate":"2021-03-21T10:25:51+0000",
      "interactionDate":"2021-03-21T10:36:03+0000",
      "sapGuid":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      "agentId":"XXXXXXXX",
      "channel":"UI5",
      "bpNumber":"XXXXXXXXX",
      "contractAccountNumber":"XXXXXXXXXX",
      "contactDirection":"",
      "contactMethod":"Z08",
      "interactionId":"XXXXXXXXXX",
      "isResponsibleForPayingBill":"Yes"
   },
   "payload":{
      "agentId":"XXXXXXX",
      "contractAccountNumber":"XXXXXXXXX",
      "readings":{
         "XXXXXXX":{
            "registers":{
               "001":{
                  "isPlausible":true,
                  "deviceNumber":"DEVICE_NUMBER",
                  "register":"001",
                  "readingValue":"08300",
                  "readingDate":"2021-03-21T00:00:00.000Z"
               }
            },
            "errors":[
               
            ],
            "bpNumber":"XXXXXXXX"
         },
         "XXXXXXX":{
            "registers":{
               "001":{
                  "isPlausible":true,
                  "deviceNumber":"DEVICENUMBER",
                  "register":"001",
                  "readingValue":"02635",
                  "readingDate":"2021-03-21T00:00:00.000Z"
               }
            },
            "errors":[
               
            ],
            "bpNumber":"XXXXX"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I've already tried the below, but neither work:

```
JSON_QUERY(data, '$.payload.*.deviceNumber' WITH WRAPPER)
JSON_QUERY(data, '$.*.deviceNumber' WITH WRAPPER)
```

My expected result would be

```
["DEVICE_NUMBER", "DEVICE_NUMBER"]
```

The json format is variable, so the below solution would not be valid:

```
JSON_QUERY(data, '$.payload.readings.*.registers.*.deviceNumber' WITH WRAPPER)
```

Comment: What version of oracle ?

Comment: Oracle 19c version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, for 19c Oracle drastically expanded their [JSON path expression syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adjsn/json-path-expressions.html#GUID-AEBAD813-99AB-418A-93AB-F96BC1658618); previously, it wasn't possible to do recursive JSON queries like this.

You were pretty close - this should work for you:

```
JSON_QUERY(data, '$..deviceNumber' with array wrapper)
```

...although I had to edit your example data, since it was invalid JSON - both `readings` child objects had the same name of `XXXXXXX`, so the second one was overwriting the first one. I renamed your second one to `XXXXXXX2` and your example works fine.

```
-- example data
with mytable as (select '{
   "session":{
      "sessionStartDate":"2021-03-21T10:25:51+0000",
      "interactionDate":"2021-03-21T10:36:03+0000",
      "sapGuid":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      "agentId":"XXXXXXXX",
      "channel":"UI5",
      "bpNumber":"XXXXXXXXX",
      "contractAccountNumber":"XXXXXXXXXX",
      "contactDirection":"",
      "contactMethod":"Z08",
      "interactionId":"XXXXXXXXXX",
      "isResponsibleForPayingBill":"Yes"
   },
   "payload":{
      "agentId":"XXXXXXX",
      "contractAccountNumber":"XXXXXXXXX",
      "readings":{
         "XXXXXXX":{
            "registers":{
               "001":{
                  "isPlausible":true,
                  "deviceNumber":"DEVICE_NUMBER",
                  "register":"001",
                  "readingValue":"08300",
                  "readingDate":"2021-03-21T00:00:00.000Z"
               }
            },
            "errors":[
               
            ],
            "bpNumber":"XXXXXXXX"
         },
         "XXXXXXX2":{
            "registers":{
               "001":{
                  "isPlausible":true,
                  "deviceNumber":"DEVICENUMBER",
                  "register":"001",
                  "readingValue":"02635",
                  "readingDate":"2021-03-21T00:00:00.000Z"
               }
            },
            "errors":[
               
            ],
            "bpNumber":"XXXXX"
         }
      }
   }
}' as data from dual)
-- actual query
select JSON_QUERY(data, '$..deviceNumber' with array wrapper) as v
from mytable;
```

Comment: Thanks! Just out of curiosity... Was there any workaround for versions earlier than 19c?

Comment: coalesce(
    JSON_QUERY(a.data, '$.*.*.deviceNumber' WITH WRAPPER),
    JSON_QUERY(a.data, '$.*.*.*.deviceNumber' WITH WRAPPER),
    JSON_QUERY(a.data, '$.*.*.*.*.deviceNumber' WITH WRAPPER),
    JSON_QUERY(a.data, '$.*.*.*.*.*.deviceNumber' WITH WRAPPER),
    JSON_QUERY(a.data, '$.*.*.*.*.*.*.deviceNumber' WITH WRAPPER)) AS device_number' guess this would be the least bad solution.

Comment: Yeah, not that I'm aware... I think you'd have to explicitly search each depth that you wanted, e.g. `'$.deviceNumber'`, `'$.*.deviceNumber'`, `'$.*.*.deviceNumber'`, etc. and union/coalesce them together. All the functions require text literals, so you can't even do your own recursion easily.